# Generating tiles for osm/esri shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, tiles, mapnik, maperitive

I've generated tiles for OpenStreetMap .OSM files using Maperitive and quickly consumed them with leaflet (with no tile cache yet).
I'm now looking for the right and simple way to do that also with the shapefiles given by OSM.

(Tried TileMill but the generated mbtiles file needs further processing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate tiles from shapefiles using [Mapnik](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/GettingStartedInPython). Just specify the shape file as the data source. There's a tutorial at their [Github wiki](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/LearningMapnik).

You can also try serving the mbtiles using [TileStache](http://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2011/09/20/serving-mbtiles-tiles-for-slippy-maps/) though it can be a bit of a pain. Another option would be to use [landez](http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/serve-your-map-layers-with-a-usual-web-hosting-service.html).

Comment: thanks, already started this route, seems Maperative still misses some features

Comment: Okay. Updated my answer to include options in case you want to try the mbtiles again. Tilemill produces good maps and it's a shame if you can't use them.

Comment: @robi actually, Maperitive supports shapefiles through its Python API. But I wouldn't say it's a "simple way", since I haven't written docs for it yet ;)

Comment: Trying now mapnik, it needs as input an XML style file. any ideas how to get a default one suitable for the OSM shapefiles? (the examples on the site are minimal, e.g., only for roads - I need for a full country data)

Comment: Please post it as another question so that others may benefit.

Comment: If you like the styling available in TileMill but don't want to export to MBTiles, you can export to a Mapnik XML style file instead, and then use a different script to render it in whatever way suits your needs.

Comment: Basically the OSM style for mapnik is here https://trac.openstreetmap.org/browser/applications/rendering/mapnik/osm.xml, I'll make it into a post when I will see the forest... thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you  to try mapnik node tile_server from this repo:
https://github.com/pocketIlmatto/mapnik_node_tile_server